# Placing new post in drafts to complete at a later time then post

Tags: facebook

Can you place a post in draft and return to complete later then post?

Answer (score 1):

Drafting is not possible for a user profile's timeline. But you can do it for a page.

You can create a draft of a post for your Page and then review, edit and publish it later.

Learn more here [How do I create a draft of a post for my Page?](https://www.facebook.com/help/642707099175171)

*Note: You should be in admin list to post anything on page.*